# Error Install CAS SERVER 4.0

Tags: maven, build, installation, cas

when i build the folder cas 4.o from maven showme the follow error:

> Failed to execute goal
>   com.mycila.maven-license-plugin:maven-license-plu gin:1.9.0:check
>   (default) on project cas-server-uber-webapp: Resource D:\Documen
>   ts\CAS_HOME/src/licensing/header.txt not found in file system,
>   classpath or URL:  unknown protocol: d -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To
>   see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
>   ch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug
>   logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and
>   possible solutions, please rea d the following articles: [ERROR] [Help
>   1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

the solution that i found was open the pom.xml i find:

${cs.dir}/src/licensing/header.txt

You can replace whit:

${licenseHeader}

And rebuild whit comand: mvn clean install

mvn package install worked for me!!